# What is the latest jQuery version to work with IE8?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

I'm working on a Bootstrap 3 site and I was having some issues with the jQuery version that I was using (1.9.1). I upgraded to 2.1.0 and my issues are gone, however, this breaks IE8 compatibility since 2.1.0 doesn't support IE8 anymore and jQuery seizes to work in this browser.

I can't use 1.1.0 because Bootstrap supports [1.9.0 or higher](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.1.1/bower.json) (also I'll have my issues back).

So the question is: Which is the highest version of jQuery that works with IE8?

The [jQuery Browser Support Page](http://jquery.com/browser-support/) only lists 1.11.0 and 1.9.1 so that's not helping.

Comment: Why can't you use jQuery 1.11.0 (the latest in the 1.x line)?  jQuery 2.x only works on IE9+, you need to use jQuery 1.x.  P.S. 1.11.0 > 1.9.0

Comment: the lastest version of the 1.x branch will always support IE8

Comment: @RocketHazmat: I state it in my question: Bootstrap only supports 1.9.0 or higher.

Comment: @AlexanderRechsteiner: So then why can't you use 1.11.0?  1.11.0 *is* higher than 1.9.0!  That's how version numbers work.  It's actually "version one dot eleven".

Comment: What issues were you having with 1.9.1?

Comment: The latest 1.x version is available on the [jQuery downloads page](http://jquery.com/download/). Browser support is listed on their [browser support page](http://jquery.com/browser-support/). Both of those pages are main menu options, by the way.

Comment: @RocketHazmat version 1.9.1 was quite buggy, but not related to bootstrap and anyway most (all?) bugs fixed in 1.10

Comment: @RocketHazmat: You're absolutely right. I'm a fool! Sorry for the disturbance. I don't know why I would think 1.9.1 is higher than 1.11.0

Comment: @AlexanderRechsteiner: We all make mistakes, it's alright! :-)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

IE8 support was dropped in jQuery 2.x, so you will want any version beginning with 1 that satisfies your plugin's version dependencies.

I would try the latest 1.11 or 1.10 first. 1.11 was released in early 2014. 1.10 was released mid-2013.

There may be **some confusion with comparing minor version numbers**. 1.11 > 1.10 > 1.9. We're comparing the second number as a number. Don't make the mistake of treating each digit as a value to compare.

- See also http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/
- All jQuery versions: http://code.jquery.com/jquery/

**Update**: latest version compatible with IE8 is now 1.11.3
http://blog.jquery.com/2015/04/28/jquery-1-11-3-and-2-1-4-released-ios-fail-safe-edition/

Comment: What is the latest non 1.X version there is? As I state in my question, Bootstrap doesn't support anything below 1.9.0, so there's that.

Comment: @AlexanderRechsteiner "What is the latest non 1.X version there is?" non 1.X??? What do you mean?

Comment: The latest version that does not start with a 2 :)

Comment: @AlexanderRechsteiner then 1.11.0 check: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

Comment: @AlexanderRechsteiner: How does "non 1.x" mean "not start with a 2"?  There are two jQuery versions.  1.x (the one you want for IE8 support, latest version is 1.11.0) and 2.x (only for modern browsers, latest version is 2.1.0).

Comment: Thank you, I'm realizing only now that 1.11.0 is actually *higher* than 1.9.0. I think my brain had some sort of mental black out when I compared those versions!