# Script5: access is denied ie8. Using IE8 emulator in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

Basically my bootstrap navbar is missing from IE 8 and below, it's collapsed so to speak.

From what I have gather this should fix it:

```html
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

Yet nothing happens. Get Access is denied on respond.js line in IE8 emulator! If anything I need some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using jQuery 1.11 and not 2+

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template

[What is the latest jQuery version to work with IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073479/what-is-the-latest-jquery-version-to-work-with-ie8)